Multi-Tenant Domains on NextJS (not Vercel)
What is the right way to assign a custom domain to a subdomain like
assume I want to use testproduction.com as the custom domain
Example:
(Multi-Tenant) subdomain: *.example.com (test.example.com)
Custom domain: testproduction.com
Assume I already have the proper middleware and everything setup.
Wildcard SSL for the subdomains, and middleware fully handled.
What are the correct records to use in the DNS for testproduction.com? Apparently CNAME can't be used for APEX domain, A record resulting in SSL errors.
My NextJS app is hosted in AWS Amplify. What are the right records?
Judging from how Vercel does it, I can use an A record for the apex domain, and a CNAME for the www.
But how do I do this in AWS amplify since I don't have an IP to point the A record to? What about SSL?

Here is an article from amplify - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/wildcard-subdomains-for-multi-tenant-apps-on-aws-amplify-hosting/

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
